# Unable to launch UI for Pact broker

Tags: user-interface, pact, broker

I installed pact broker using Docker-compose file. And able to run it successfully on port 9292. But i am unable to access the Ui for it. It doesnt return any index page for it. So am unable to verify the pacts or versions published. Kindly help me with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Aarti, thanks for the question. We need a lot more info to help you:

1. Please show what you have done to get to where you are
2. What have you tried that is / is not working? (e.g. logs)
3. Ideally, a reproducible example so that others can try and fix it

Comment: can you also provide the log on the docker-compose task once you try to hit the URL, does the docker gives any error log?